# VBA: how to connect powerpoint shapes after selecting them

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I just want to connect 2 squares after selecting them.

My code below doesn't work, can't see how to fix it:

```
Sub ConnectSelectedShapes()

Dim shpFirst As Shape
Dim shpSecond As Shape

Dim shpShapes As Shapes

Set shapesRange = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange

Set shpFirst = shapesRange(1)
Set shpSecond = shapesRange(2)

With shpShapes.AddConnector(Type:=msoConnectorCurve, BeginX:=0, _
        BeginY:=0, EndX:=100, EndY:=100).ConnectorFormat

    .BeginConnect ConnectedShape:=shpFirst, ConnectionSite:=1
    .EndConnect ConnectedShape:=shpSecond, ConnectionSite:=1
    .Parent.RerouteConnections

End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've delcared `shpShapes`, however you haven't defined it...

```
Set shpShapes = ActiveWindow.View.Slide.Shapes
```

And, of course, you'll need to make sure that 2 shapes have been selected before running the code.

Hope this helps!